# Generic function which takes a pointer to another generic function, same T

Tags: go

Tinkering and I feel like there must be some way to express this in Go, but I can't figure it out.

I have a generic function (simplified):

```
type signed interface {
    ~int | ~int8 | ~int16 | ~int32 | ~int64
}

func GEZ[T signed](value T) error {
    if value >= 0 {
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New("must be greater than zero")
}
```

I want to make it easy to write things like:

```
if foo != nil {
    if err := GEZ(*foo); err != nil {
        accumulator = append(accumulator, err)
    }
}
```

I was thinking something like:

```
    if err := NilOr(GEZ, *foo); err != nil {
        accumulator = append(accumulator, err)
    }
```

...but I can not figure how to express `NilOr()`

I tried:

```
func NilOr[T any, F func(T) error](fn F, ptr *T) error {
    if ptr == nil {
        return nil
    }
    return fn(*ptr)
}
```

```
func NilOr[T any](fn func(T) error, ptr *T) error {
    if ptr == nil {
        return nil
    }
    return fn(*ptr)
}
```

...and some other variations, but the call-site comes back with "cannot use
generic function GEZ without instantiation",

Am I missing some trick that doesn't involve spelling out the type of T?

Comment: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Instantiations: "A generic function that is **not** called **requires** a type argument list for instantiation;" -- You're not calling `GEZ`, you're just passing it as argument, therefore you need to explicitly instantiate it by providing the type argument list.

Comment: I was hoping there was some clever way to do this seemingly (to me) obvious thing.